# Connecting MS SQL using freetds and unixodbc: isql - no default driver specified

Tags: server, database, sql

I am trying to connect to the MS SQL database using *freetds* and *unixodbc*. I have read various guides how to do it, but no one works fine for me. When I try to connect to the database using *isql* tool, I get the following error:

```
$ isql -v TS username password
[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Have anybody already successfully established the connection to the MS SQL database using *freetds* and *unixodbc* on Ubuntu 12.04? I would really appreciate some help.

Below is the procedure I used to configure the *freetds* and *unixodbc*. Thanks for your help in advance!

#### Procedure

First, I have installed the following packages with:

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev freetds-dev tdsodbc
```

and configured *freetds* as follows:

```
--- /etc/freetds/freetds.conf ---
[TS]
host = SERVER
port = 1433
tds version = 7.0
client charset = UTF-8
```

Using *tsql* tool I can successfully connect to the database by executing

```
tsql -S TS -U username -P password
```

As I need an *odbc* connection I configured *odbcinst.ini* as follows:

```
--- /etc/odbcinst.ini ---
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
FileUsage = 1
CPTimeout =
CPResuse  =
client charset = utf-8
```

and *odbc.ini* as follows:

```
--- /etc/odbc.ini ---
[TS]
Description = "test"
Driver = FreeTDS
Servername = SERVER
Server = SERVER
Port = 1433
Database = DBNAME
Trace = No
```

Trying to connect to the database using *isql* tool with such a configuration results the following error:

```
$ isql -v TS username password
[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Comment: To use `tsql` : `sudo apt-get install freetds-bin`

Answer (score 17):

Thanks, your post was very useful for me.  I was able to get it to work by eliminating the following lines from my odbcinst.ini file

```
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
FileUsage = 1
CPTimeout =
CPResuse  =
client charset = utf-8
```

so now my odbcinst.ini file looks like this:

```
--- /etc/odbcinst.ini ---
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
```

and my odbc.ini file looks like this now:

```
--- /etc/odbc.ini ---
[TS]
Description = "test"
Driver = FreeTDS
Server = SERVER
Port = 1433
Database = DBNAME
```

Once I simplified everything it worked great.   I still can't get it to work with RODBC but it worked with isql.

I don't know if this will help but your post helped me.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, definitely related to missing driver in `/etc/odbcinst.ini`

Comment: Hey great answer but unfortunately I wasn't able to make it work, even though copying your files. any thoughts on the reason why ? it is pretty much the same, except that on the SERVER part I use an IP not a name. do you think that could be it ? thanks a lot

Answer (score 14):

This is a minimal but complete example how to connect to [Azure SQL Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Azure) with `isql` from Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. The example is extracted from [How To Connect Azure SQL Database From Ubuntu](https://bitbucket.org/janihur/devoops/wiki/How%20To%20Connect%20Azure%20SQL%20Database%20From%20Ubuntu) (disclaimer: it's my personal wiki).

**Install necessary packages**

```
$ sudo apt-get -y install freetds-bin tdsodbc unixodbc
```

**Configure FreeTDS**

File `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf`

```
[global]
tds version = 7.1

[<SERVERNAME>]
host = <HOST>.database.windows.net
port = 1433
```

**Test connection**

At this point connecting with `tsql` should work:

```
$ tsql -S <SERVERNAME> -U <USERNAME>@<HOST> -P <PASSWORD>
```

Note that `@<HOST>` is required. Otherwise the connection ends with an error:

```
Msg 40531 (severity 11, state 1) from [<SERVERNAME>] Line 1:
    "Server name cannot be determined.  It must appear as the first segment of the server's dns name (servername.database.windows.net).  Some libraries do not send the server name, in which case the server name must be included as part of the user name (username@servername).  In addition, if both formats are used, the server names must match."
Error 20002 (severity 9):
    Adaptive Server connection failed
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

**Configure ODBC driver**

File `/etc/odbcinst.ini`

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS Driver
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
```

**Configure ODBC data sources**

File `/etc/odbc.ini`

```
[<DATA_SOURCE_NAME>]
Driver = FreeTDS
Servername = <SERVERNAME>
Port = 1433
Database = <DBNAME>
```

`<SERVERNAME>` is the same than in `freetds.conf`.

**Connect with isql**

```
$ isql -v <DATA_SOURCE_NAME> <USER>@<HOST> <PASSWORD>
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL> select current_timestamp
+------------------------+
|                        |
+------------------------+
| 2015-01-02 09:05:55.593|
+------------------------+
SQLRowCount returns 1
1 rows fetched
SQL>
```

Note that `@<HOST>` is required. Otherwise the connection ends with an error:

```
[S1000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source
[37000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Server name cannot be determined.  It must appear as the first segment of the server's dns name (servername.database.windows.net).  Some libraries do not send the server name, in which case the server name must be included as part of the user name (username@servername).  In addition, if both formats are used, the server names must match.
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Comment: The `@<HOST>` no longer appears to be required.

Answer (score 8):

In my case the problem arose because of simple indents in my config file. So in `/etc/odbc.ini`, I **removed all indents** and voila!

(`odbcinst.ini` behaves like a normal kid and doesn't seem to throw any tantrums.)

Comment: THANK YOU!  I have been staring that this config for 2 hours trying to figure out that white space was the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu prior to 12.04 had a different odbc path in the /etc/odbcinst.ini file.

The old driver path was:

```
Driver = /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
```

I changed it to:

```
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
```

Here's the full configuration:

```
--- /etc/odbcinst.ini ---
[FreeTDS]
Description = tdsodbc
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
FileUsage = 1
CPTimeout = 5
CPReuse = 5
```

Works like a charm now!  Thanks!

Comment: Is the setup line deprecated, now?