# Configure FreeTDS to connect to MS SQL

Tags: drivers, iodbc

I’ve tried several different config options based on this page (http://enlook.wordpress.com/2013/05/02/error-sql-error-unixodbcdriver-managerdata-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified/#comment-2783)

And a very similar post here at [Connecting MS SQL using freetds and unixodbc: isql - no default driver specified](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167491/connecting-ms-sql-using-freetds-and-unixodbc-isql-no-default-driver-specified) however when I try to test the connection with isql I continue to get “[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect”.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server and installed freeTDS via `apt-get`.

results of `odbcinst -q -d`:

```
@cabana:/etc# odbcinst -q -d
[TDSDRIVER]
```

results of odbcinst -q- s

```
@cabana:/etc# odbcinst -q -s
[MSSQL]
[SQL01]
```

tds.driver.template:

```
@cabana:/etc# cat tds.driver.template
[TDSDRIVER]
Description = FreeTDS driver
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
FileUsage = 1
UsageCount =1
```

tds.datasource.template:

```
@cabana:/etc# cat tds.datasource.template
[SQL01]
Driver = TDSDRIVER # name that we specified in the driver file
Description = MSSQL ODBC Driver
Trace = No
TraceFile = /var/log/freetds.log
Server = 10.0.0.200 # this name specified in the freetds.conf
Port = 1433
Database = MyDatabase
TDS_Version = 8.0
```

freetds.conf:

```
@cabana:/etc# cat freetds.conf
[global]
tds version = 8.0
[MICROSOFT]
host = 10.0.0.200
port = 1433
tds version = 8.0
```

odbc.ini:

```
@cabana:/etc# cat odbc.ini
[MSSQL]
Driver = FreeTDS # name that we specified in the driver file
Description = MSSQL ODBC Driver
Trace = No
TraceFile = /var/log/freetds.log
Servername = 10.0.0.200 # this name specified in the freetds.conf
Port = 1433
Database = MyDatabase
TDS_Version = 7.0

[SQL01]
Driver = TDSDRIVER # name that we specified in the driver file
Description = MSSQL ODBC Driver
Trace = No
TraceFile = /var/log/freetds.log
Server = 10.0.0.200 # this name specified in the freetds.conf
Port = 1433
Database = MyDatabase
TDS_Version = 8.0
```

odbcinst.ini:

```
@cabana:/etc# cat odbcinst.ini
[TDSDRIVER]
Description = FreeTDS driver
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
FileUsage = 1
UsageCount = 2
```

tsql is not installed so testing with isql I get this:

```
@cabana:/etc# isql -v SQL01 user pass
[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas on this? I see there is still no response.

Comment: I'm trying to create an odbc sql-server connection and I'm on the same point. But there is one thing, you could use `tsql`. There is a tool that helps you test your connection:

Comment: Are you sure that your odbcinst is reading the config from the right path? Try with -j option of odbcinst: `odbcinst -j`

Comment: Yes it is reading from the right path. Unfortunately tsql does not install with the Ubuntu odbc package.

Answer (score 0):

I just came out with a similar issue: The problems with MS SQL can be ports or instances.
I suggest you to run:

```
tsql -LH [SERVER_IP_ADR]
```

Get port number and update `freetds.conf`

If your server is using instances (i.e. Instance name differs from MSSQLSERVER) you can also try to update   `/etc/odbc.ini` with:

```
Server  = [SERVER_IP_ADR]\\[INSTANCE_NAME]
```

It worked for me.

<sub>*Replace square brackets with the respective value.*</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I long ago just switched to using curl to a Windows server which I used to query MS SQL and return the data which works great, but I will look into this.

Comment: Sorry, what does the option LH exactly do ?

Comment: Although I can query the DB with tsql, `tsql -LH Server_IP` doesn't return a thing. any ideas why ?