# MS SQL/SpagoBI/Tomcat/Ubuntu

Tags: server, tomcat

I am new to Ubuntu, and have some questions.
I am trying to connect an Ubuntu server to MS SQL so that SpagoBI can get information from the MS SQL server.
Now I have followed a couple of forums and tips, but I'm just a total idiot when it comes to Ubuntu and configuring programs in Ubuntu.
I need someone who can assist me step by step on what to do, I have already installed ODBC, Java drivers etc.
But am stuck on how to actually get the two servers to communicate, and how to get SpagoBI on Tomcat to see information in MS SQL.

Comment: Please post the specific error you`re having.

Comment: Hi Pabi, there is no specific error...  I am merely in need of assistance on how to..  From where I left off to the end of the configuration.   I follow forums but it just doesn't help me...  Need expert assistance.

Comment: The question is a bit to broad then and not Ubuntu specific.

Comment: I have done most of what's in here --> https://askubuntu.com/questions/167491/connecting-ms-sql-using-freetds-and-unixodbc-isql-no-default-driver-specified  >  But when it comes to configuring the configuration file etc, I space out because of my lack of knowledge on Ubuntu...  Help please

Comment: I understand..  Let me rephrase, how would you have connected SpagoBI in Tomcat to connect to MS SQL data?   That's my aim, but need help doing that.... On Ubuntu

Comment: I have no knowledge in `SpagoBI`, but I don't think the configuration is Ubuntu specific. It should be the same in any linux distro

Comment: Okay thank you...  Any other tips you can give me?

Comment: You can ask your question at [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).