# linux and MSSQLServer

Tags: server

I have an application in Linux and a database in Windows based pc in MSSqlserver. Yet my application can not connect to sqlserver.this is while it replies as I ping the target pc which the data base is in it.
Does anybody know how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/167491/connecting-ms-sql-using-freetds-and-unixodbc-isql-no-default-driver-specified  and https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/tdsodbc/ should do the trick.